# Using multiple skips in Ginkgo test run

Tags: go, ginkgo

I am running tests using ginkgo, and I am trying to skip two of my tests that are not applicable to my environment.

> ./_output/bin/e2e.test --ginkgo.focus="sig-network.*[Conformance]" --ginkgo.skip=".*should delete a collection of services.*" --ginkgo.skip=".*A set of valid responses are returned for both pod and service Proxy.*" --provider=aws --gce-zone=us-west-2a

This is not skipping both the test regexes. It is skipping only one of them. How can I skip both the conditions mentioned above.

- I have tried using `|`

Comment: What are the names of the tests you're skipping?

Comment: What is `e2e.test` and how does it pass through to ginkgo?

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes both start and end with a `.` meaning they must have at least one character before and after your string. `.foo.` will not match `foo`. It will match `xfoox` or `foo` (there's spaces before and after).

I expect you have a test named something like `This should delete a collection of services.` which matches, but `A set of valid responses are returned for both pod and service Proxy.` does not match because there's nothing before the A.

Simply remove the leading and trailing `.`.